# Are the introspection functions an example of the observer design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, introspection

I am confused about the difference between observer design pattern and introspection in php.
for example the function class_exists() – it checks whether a class has been defined - is an introspection function.
So is it an example of observer design pattern?

Answer (score 1):

No, the introspection functions are not an example of the observer design pattern.

The [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) describes the possibility for a e.g. class (the observer) to be notified about changes of another class (the subject).

The introspection functions are functions used for [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29). The perspective is the other way round. The subject is not notified, but has to know what it is looking for.

Comment: thank you Psix.Can you please give me small programming exmaple for observer design pattern

Comment: Here is a link to an example implementation in php: http://www.labelmedia.co.uk/blog/php-design-patterns-observer-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Not at all.

The observer design pattern consists in being able to add observers to an observable object, so that the observable object notifies all its observers when something happens.

A typical example is a button click handler. You register an observer (the click handler) to the button (the observable) in order for this handler to be notified when the button is clicked.